# How to add Event Listeners to UseRefs within UseEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, usecallback, use-ref

I want to add an `eventListener` to a node in my React component. I am selecting the node with a `useRef` hook. I am `useCallback` since the `useRef` is `null` on it's first render.

```
const offeringsContainer = useRef(null);

const setOfferingsContainer = useCallback((node) => {
  if (node !== null) {
    offeringsContainer.current = node;
  }
}, []);
```

My issue is that my `useEffect` is not reacting to any changes done to the `offeringContainer` ref. Meaning, `offeringContainer.current` is `null`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    checkHeaderState();
    offeringsContainer.current.addEventListener("wheel", onOfferingsContainerWheel, { passive: false });
}, [offeringsContainer.current]);
```

This is my JSX:

```
return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="card-business-products-services-title-text">
        Products &amp; Services
      </div>
      <div
        className="card-business-products-services-container"
        id="card-business-products-services-container"
        onWheel={onOfferingsContainerWheel}
        ref={setOfferingsContainer}
      >
        {renderOfferings()}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
);
```

I know I am doing something incorrectly, but my useEffect hook should be listening to any changes from `offeringsContainer.current`.

Comment: You can simply assign the ref in the jsx: `ref={offeringsContainer}` and since `useEffect` runs after the first render accessing `offeringsContainer.current` will return the node. You'll also want to pass a cleanup call back to the return of your `useEffect` that removes the listener. But even better would be to use the [`onwheel`](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#wheel-events) synthetic event

Comment: why are you assigning `onWheel` to the element and also manually adding a listener?

Comment: @pilchard to remove the “passive: true”

Comment: Doing both assigns two listeners so choose one or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just past `offeringsContainer` to the `ref` of the component. `useEffect` will be invoked only when there is first rendering that's why your `offeringsContainer.current` will not be `null`.

And you forgot to remove listener after the component will be unmounted.

Your code should be like this;

```
const offeringsContainer = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
  checkHeaderState();
  offeringsContainer.current.addEventListener(
    "wheel",
    onOfferingsContainerWheel,
    { passive: false }
  );

  return () => offeringsContainer.current.removeEventListener("wheel");
}, []);

return (
  <Fragment>
    <div className="card-business-products-services-title-text">
      Products &amp; Services
    </div>
    <div
      className="card-business-products-services-container"
      id="card-business-products-services-container"
      onWheel={onOfferingsContainerWheel}
      ref={offeringsContainer}
    >
      {renderOfferings()}
    </div>
  </Fragment>
);
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-banzai-3fhju?file=/src/App.js